# Strange error while importing jar lib - IntelliJ IDEA 14

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I have created a own java lib and build a UTALib.jar file.

I copied this lib into my java Project and marked it as compile under Module Dependencies.

For testing i created two classes: class1 and class2.

I have the following structure:

```
|TestApp
| -- src
    | -- test/
        |-- class2.java
    | -- class1.java
    | -- UTALib.jar
```

The problem is now: in class1 i can access all my lib methods, but in class2 its not possible!

In the editor the called functions are marked red in class2 and the compailer says: cannot find symbol

I have no idea to solve this problem - so what can i do???

Comment: What was your error message and what code did you try?

Comment: cannot find symbol....

Comment: Please edit that into your question rather than posting it as a comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So i found the Solution:

The lib has to be changed from this structure:

```
|lib
| -- src
    | -- libClass1.java
    | -- more classes...
```

To something like that:

```
|lib
| -- src
    | -- packageName
        | -- libClass1.java
```

Answer (score 0):

It's look like that you have two some lib in classpath (or two version of one lib). Open class1 in IDEA (Ctrl + click mouse), then IDEA show what lib has this class (in project view) and show you your lib in decompile mode. After that you could found what lib using and what version of lib using.